# How to allow file:// for OAuth request on Google

Tags: cordova, google-oauth

I am trying to use Google Drive (https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/) inside my phonegap app.

Now I currently having the problem, after setting up an "Client ID for installed applications", that api requests from file:// are not supported? Or they not allowed?

The following code ends end with 400 Bad Request:
    gapi.auth.authorize({
        'client_id' : CLIENT_ID,
        'scope' : SCOPES,
        'immediate' : false
    }, handleAuthResult);

The called URL https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=XXX&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fdrive&immediate=true&proxy=oauth2relay427605398&redirect_uri=postmessage&origin=file%3A%2F%2F&response_type=token&state=2033446467%7C0.4181954479&authuser=0 **does not work with origin file**?

Can I allow access from file scope? Or how to use this inside a phonegap container.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can use file:// as an origin.  I have not found an example of using phonegap in this way.

You can however use a childbrowser and make an authenticated request from it and pass it back to your browser.  There is a post and an example app using Google Tasks at the links below.

http://www.itsalif.info/content/oauth-google-api-gapi-phonegap-childbrowser-jquery

https://github.com/liquidlabs/phonegap-oauth-google-api-mobile

Comment: this doesn't work because http://localhost doesn't work on ios and android. It only works on emulators

Comment: it worked on my real android device...have you tried the demo app?

Comment: It will work if you have a localhost server running on your local network, but that should not be the presumed behavior at all. G oto localhost in your browser, if that works, it means that you have localhost server running. Not a lot of non-developer have that.